# forEach method issue with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a problem where the forEach method is working for spread operators but it is not working for arrays. I get the "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" error with my array code.

Attached is my code with arrays which does not work and the second part is replaced with spread operator where it works. Why is it not working with arrays? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
//this does not work (arrays)
 const calcTip = bills => {
 const tips = [];
 bills.array.forEach(bill => {
  const tip = bill >= 50 && bill <= 300
   ? 0.15*bill
   : 0.20*bill
  tips.push(tip);
 });
 return tips
}

console.log(calcTip([1,2,3]));

//this works (spread operator)
const calcTip = (...bills) => {
 const tips = [];
 bills.forEach(bill => {
  const tip = bill >= 50 && bill <= 300
   ? 0.15*bill
   : 0.20*bill
  tips.push(tip);
 });
 return tips
}

console.log(calcTip(4,23,435));
```

Comment: `bills.array.forEach` should be `bills.forEach`. Arrays do not have an `array` property

Comment: And you should actually use `Array.map()` since you are transforming the items of an array, and returning a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `bills.array.forEach` with simply `bills.forEach`. There is no property called `array` on arrays (i.e. it's undefined) and hence when you try to do `arrays.forEach` it tells you `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"`

Here's the code fixed:

```js
const calcTip = bills => {
 const tips = [];
 bills.forEach(bill => {
  const tip = bill >= 50 && bill <= 300
   ? 0.15*bill
   : 0.20*bill
  tips.push(tip);
 });
 return tips
}

console.log(calcTip([1, 2, 3]));
```

You can even modify the code to use map instead:

```js
const calcTip = bills => {
 const tips = bills.map(bill => {
  return bill >= 50 && bill <= 300
   ? 0.15*bill
   : 0.20*bill
 });
 return tips
}

console.log(calcTip([1, 2, 3]));
```